# Software for drawing generalized Petersen graphs

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, reference-request

I am doing some problem on generalized Petersen graphs $P(n,k)$. With large values of $n$, it is tough to draw it manually for further calculations. Is there any software or tool to generate any generalized Petersen graph, other than Mathematica or Matlab?

Comment: @Moo That might be helpful! But where to draw/plot these graphs. Like if I want to draw generalized Petersen graph $P(,40,9)$?

Comment: @Moo... So, we need to enter the data that which vertex is adjacent to which? right?

Comment: @Moo Thanks a lot for the help. It is working but edges cannot be seen properly. Actually, I am trying to find the distance between vertices. For the same, I was seeking for figures.

Comment: @Moo Yeah,. Thanks a lot for your efforts.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you want an adjacency representation of the graph or an embedding into the plane.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I want the embedding into the plane.